# Как правильно организовать БД?

Tags: база-данных, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, проектирование

Добрый день.

Разрабатываю систему онлайн-тестов на ASP MVC 5, в связи с чем возник по организации базы данных (EF6).
В системе есть тест, в котором есть вопросы. Вопросы можно редактировать, удалять из теста и т.п.

Ситуация 1: тест выдан в состоянии А студентам, после чего был отредактирован в состояние Б. В результате ссылки в результатах теста, ведущие на А становятся неактуальными.
Ситуация 2: из пройденного теста удаляем вопрос. Удалить из базы мы его не можем, т.к. тогда результаты будут неверными, но и не удалить из списка вопросов также не можем, т.к. тогда теряется связь с тестом.

В качестве решения я предполагаю сделать привязку всех сущностей ко времени (т.е. ссылка в результатах теста будет на вопрос с Id=XXX и временем изменения=YYY). Но как быть с удалением - я не понимаю.

Посоветуйте, что тут можно сделать.

```
public class ExerciseSet
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    [Display(Name = "Название")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ExerciseBlock> ExercisesBlocks { get; set; } = new List<ExerciseBlock>();
    public virtual List<GeneratedVariant> GeneratedVariants { get; set; } = new List<GeneratedVariant>();

    [Display(Name = "Примечания")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public ExerciseSet()
    {
    }

    public ExerciseSet(string ownerId)
    {
        Owner = ownerId;
    }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Кол-во заданий")]
    public int ExercisesCount => ExercisesBlocks.SelectMany(x => x.Exercises).Count();
}

public class ExerciseBlock
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Название")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ExerciseSet ExerciseSet {get; set; }

    public virtual List<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
}

public class Exercise
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ExerciseBlock ExerciseBlock { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Список блоков вопроса, блоки выводятся в соотв. с порядком
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Блоки вопроса")]
    public virtual IList<Resource> AskBlocks { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Ответ на вопрос
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Варианты ответа")]
    public virtual IList<ExerciseAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
    public string AnswerType { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Подсказка для режима Обучения
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Подсказка (Обучение)")]
    public string Hint { get;set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Id тестируемого предмета
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Предмет")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Id тестируемой темы
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Тема")]
    public string Topic { get; set; } = "";

    /// <summary>
    /// Id тестируемого класса
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Класс")]
    public string Class { get; set; } = "";
    /// <summary>
    /// Id используемого кодификатора
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Кодификатор")]
    public virtual Codificator Codificator { get; set; }
    public int? CodificatorId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Номер проверяемого элемента по кодификатору
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Элемент кодификатора")]
    public virtual CodificatorSection CodificatorElement { get; set; }
    public int? CodificatorElementId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Номер требования к подготовке по кодификатору.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Требование кодификатора")]
    public virtual CodificatorSection CodificatorRequirement { get; set; }
    public int? CodificatorRequirementId { get; set; }
    ///// <summary>
    ///// Сложность (базовая, повышенная, высокая)
    ///// </summary>
    //[Display(Name = "Сложность")]
    //public ExerciseBlock Difficulty { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Время выполнения задания
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Время на выполнение задания")]
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Кол-во баллов за выполнение задания
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Количество баллов")]
    public int Points { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Заметка к заданию
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Примечания")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public Exercise()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        AskBlocks = new List<Resource>();
        Answers = new List<ExerciseAnswer>();
    }
}
```

Comment: а для чего редактировать вопрос??? может стоит завести ему признак `bool IsActive`, и при необходимости создавать новый вопрос - возможные ответы на него, а старый прятать для тех кто будет проходить тесты вновь. аналогично можно поступить с удалением, т.е. прятать его а не фактически удалять

Comment: Согласен с комментом выше. Добавлю, сталкивался с похожей ситуацией, но на примере учетных записей к системе. Человек, например, увольняется и вопрос: удалять его учетку или просто блокировать. Удалять плохо, т.к. он фигурирует в логах и как автор определенных операций. Но такой подход не безопасен (правда у Вас такого вопроса не стоит...пока).

Comment: Пример: составлен тест на знания математики. В тесте допущена ошибка, тест уже выдан на решение.Предположим, часть студентов прошла его, часть ещё нет. В этом случае будут показаны разные вопросы разным студентам в ходе одного теста. Другой пример: тест выдан 1 группе, но вопрос сформулирован не слишком корректно. Вопрос исправляется перед выдачей 2 группе. Нужно выдать подробную информацию на каждого ученика в виде вопрос-ответ-верный ответ (в текстовом виде). При исправлении вопроса изначальный текст вопроса теряется.

Comment: если тест находится в стадии прохождения, мне кажется неправильным его редактировать, в крайнем случае не учитывать при подсчете результатов у всей тестируемой группы

Comment: Да, первая ситуация представляется исключительной. Однако, вторая - жизненная, исходя из ТЗ. Вопрос в том, как сохранить оба варианта вопроса, чтобы не потерять связи в EF, но при этом чтобы EF не воспринимал старый вопрос как часть списка. Т.е. чтобы из свойства типа Exercise.Test получить тест, но чтобы Test.ExersisesList содержал исключительно действующие вопросы.

Comment: ну так введение свойства `IsActive` позволит это делать, при получении списка вопросов фильтруете по этому полю

Comment: сразу рассмотрите возможность выведения вопросов/ответов в разном порядке при каждом тестировании,

Comment: Хорошо. Я верно понял, что идея в том, что при удалении ставить флаг, а при редактировании/добавлении добавлять новый элемент? Тогда вопрос такой: в вопросе есть набор блоков вопроса (текст, картинки и т.п.) и набор ответов на вопрос. Получается, что в таком случае нужно копировать вопрос со всеми вложенными элементами? p.s. генерация непосредственно заданий для выдачи (по выбранным темам, кодификаторам, сложности и т.п.) из набора заданий уже есть и работает в целом неплохо.

Comment: а как у Вас сейчас организована связь между *ресурсами* и вопросом, ведь одинаковые картинки могут быть в нескольких вопросах, не храните же вы одинаковые ресурсы? и если пишите какому либо пользователю в комментарии то пишите его ник вот так @Bald, тогда придет нотификация

Comment: @Bald, предполагаю, что ресурс типа картинка, видео, будет содержать только ссылку на картинку/видео. Пока работает для внешних картинок, позже будет загрузка в хранилище пользователя. Т. е.  два разных ресурса могут ссылаться на один файл на сервере. Перезапись файла вроде бы не закладыватся.

Comment: тогда не вижу никаких проблем, при редактировании вопроса Вы копируете существующий, вместе со связями на необходимые ресурсы, вносите соответствующие изменения, сохраняете, исходный вопрос помечаете как не активный, при формировании тестов отбираете только активные вопросы